# parsing lambdas for dynamic database validation rules

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamic, lambda

I have a situation where I'm needing to copy a bunch of records from one database to another, and the transfer involves a lot of transformation. I have run into a case where in addition to transformation, I need to validate and reject certain column values in the source data. (For example, I'm dealing with weights of dogs and cats, and occasional typos in the source data resulted in exorbitant weights that are obviously incorrect, but were never validated in the source data.) Anyway, these exorbitant weights aren't allowed in the new database, so I have to identify and set those bad values aside.

What I want is to have a rule as a string expression that I can invoke during the transformation. The rule is stored with the column mapping instruction. The particulars of that aren't my question, but rather how to turn a plain string expression into a runtime expression.

(preface: I have muddled around with lambdas a fair amount, but I get tripped up all the time.) Here's what I have.... I have an IsValid method that accepts a value from a SqlDataReader. The partial class ColumnRow is from a DataSet, and it has a ValidationRule string property referenced in the code below.

Basically, if there is no rule specified or if the incoming value is null, then assume it's valid. Otherwise, parse a lambda from the ValidationRule. The rule I need to make work in my particular situation is simply "value < 1000"--just to give some context.

```
partial class ColumnRow
{
    public bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == DBNull.Value) return true;
        if (IsValidationRuleNull()) return true;

        string exprString = "value => { return " + ValidationRule + "; }";
        // fails here: No property or field 'value' exists in type 'Object'
        var expr = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<object, bool>(exprString);
        var method = expr.Compile();
        return method.Invoke(value);
    }
}
```

Instead of doing all this, I could add some hard-coded criteria to the source SQL statements, but stuff is already rather complicated on the SQL side so I'd rather not modify the incoming SQL.

Comment: I know is not a direct answer to your question but you could use an SSIS package and ETL this. Perfect use case. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services

Comment: I know SSIS is meant for this, but I never thought it was good for handling foreign keys that end up changed in a target database. My feeling about SSIS in general is that doesn't scale well to complex scenarios. Mine is a multi-tenant system, and I'm moving customers one at a time to a new database, which means keys are all different in the target db (can't use identity insert). For that reason, a bunch of foreign keys are impacted and have to be "remapped" to new primary keys. So, I have a special app for just this kind of thing....